# Library with xkeyval, fp and newcommand

Tags: macros, xkeyval, fp

Been searching the net here and did not find any solution to this.
I am having some problems with a defined library structure (`xkeyval`) with FPeval calculation and then passing this information/calculation towards the FPeval in the document. I would basically like to make a big library of key/values and do a bunch of calculations with them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\usepackage{xkeyval}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval
\usepackage{siunitx} %Adding SI-prefixes
\sisetup{
exponent-to-prefix = true,
round-mode         = figures,
round-precision    = 3,
scientific-notation = engineering
}%
%
%
\newcommand \Family[1]{\setkeys{RESFamily}{#1}}%
\makeatletter
%
\define@key{RESFamily}{Name}{ \newcommand \RESFamilyName{#1} }%
\define@key{RESFamily}{Value}{ \newcommand \RESFamilyValue{#1} }%
%
\makeatother
%
\AtBeginDocument{
%##################################################################################################
\Family{%
    Name = Some text here,%
    Value = ,%Value is added in the LIBRARY components
}%
%
\newcommand \defRES[3]{%START of \defRES
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1Name\endcsname{\csname RES#2Name\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1Value\endcsname{#3}% 1
%With this now i am having problems
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1Max\endcsname{% START of MAX FPeval
        \ensuremath{\FPeval{\RtmpMax}{round( \csname #1Value\endcsname * (1+20/100) :4 )}}\RtmpMax%
    }%END of MAX FPeval
%
\ignorespaces}%END of \defRES
%
%LIBRARY
\defRES{Rone}{Family}{10}%
%
}%
%
\begin{document}

test = \RoneName\\
test = \RoneValue\\

\FPeval{\resultTwo}{round( 2*2 :2)}
test2 = 2 * 2 =\resultTwo\\

\FPeval{\resultThree}{round( \RoneValue * \RoneValue :2)}
test3 = \RoneValue * \RoneValue = \resultThree\\
test3a = \RoneValue * \RoneValue = \num{\resultThree}\\
%until now everything OK

test3a = \num[parse-numbers=false]{\RoneMax}\\% this offcourse works
%now NOK
test3a = \num{\RoneMax}
\FPeval{\resultFour}{round( \RoneMax * \RoneMax :2)}
test3 = \resultFour \\
test3a = \num{\resultFour}
\end{document}
```

If there are any more question regarding this just ask. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the question? At the moment, your example doesn't compile

Comment: That was intentional and that is the problem - why the code is not compiling as I would like is the question. To successfully compile you can comment the lines below the comment "now NOK" for easier comparison.

Comment: The `\ensuremath` is wrong in my point of view, but it's not the cause of the problems

Comment: Yes, tried also without that but it is the same. I think i'm not doing something right with "sending" the right numbers outside the FPeval as in: 
`\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1Max\endcsname
{% START of MAX FPeval
        \ensuremath{\FPeval{\RtmpMax}{round( \csname #1Value\endcsname * (1+20/100) :4 )}}\RtmpMax%
    }%END of MAX FPeval`

Comment: I expect that `\RoneMax` have non-number content in its output which makes `\num` without `parse-numbers=false` fail

Comment: Is there anyway that I could check the outputs for these numbers in Latex? For instance, with the `\xkvview` output I only get the defined key=values that I use, but not with information/numbers assigned to each one.

Comment: I don't think it's related to `xkeyval`. I'll notice Joseph Wright, he's the author of `siunitx` (amongst other packages)

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have done some more tests to check the number format (with a package `xstring` and if I put `\IfDecimal{\RtmpMax}{1}{0}` inside the `\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1Max\endcsname{ ... }` the output of this is "1" but this number then still cannot be used in further calculations with `FPeval` or under `siunitx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I have found a possible solution for this. I have rearanged the `\defRES` macro to be something like this:

```
\newcommand \defRES[3]{%START of \defRES
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1Name\endcsname{\csname RES#2Name\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1Value\endcsname{#3}% 1 %
    \FPeval{#1Max}{round( \csname #1Value\endcsname * (1+20/100) :4 )}%
\ignorespaces}%END of \defRES
```

and now I can printout a number from `\num`, `\SI` (without the  parameter `[parse-numbers=false]`) and it also works for further calculations with `\FPeval`.