# Library with xkeyval, make my life easier?

Tags: macros, xkeyval, fp

Question is related to the topic that I opened last year regarding the [Library with xkeyval, fp and newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270698/library-with-xkeyval-fp-and-newcommand) where the library now grew quite big and adding new stuff in it has become tedious and more and more error prone.

I would like now to extend and perhaps simplify this code to make my life easier and not to brake the fp calculations. For instance, at the moment I am just copy pasting code and then changing names to differentiate between the Families (e.g. RESFamilyOne, RESFamilyTwo, RESFamilyThree and etc.).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\usepackage{xkeyval}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval
\usepackage{siunitx} %Adding SI-prefixes
\sisetup{
exponent-to-prefix = true,
round-mode         = figures,
round-precision    = 3,
scientific-notation = engineering
}%
%
%
\newcommand \Family[1]{\setkeys{RESFamily}{#1}}%
\makeatletter
%
\define@key{RESFamily}{Name}{ \newcommand \RESFamilyName{#1} }%
\define@key{RESFamily}{Value}{ \newcommand \RESFamilyValue{#1} }%
%
\makeatother
%
\AtBeginDocument{
%##################################################################################################
\Family{%
    Name = Some text here,%
    Value = ,%Value is added in the LIBRARY components
}%
%
\newcommand \defRES[3]{%START of \defRES
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1Name\endcsname{\csname RES#2Name\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1Value\endcsname{#3}% 1 %
    \FPeval{#1Max}{round( \csname #1Value\endcsname * (1+20/100) :4 )}%
\ignorespaces}%END of \defRES
%
%
%LIBRARY
\defRES{Rone}{Family}{10}%
%
}%
%
\begin{document}

test = \RoneName\\
test = \RoneValue\\

\FPeval{\resultTwo}{round( 2*2 :2)}
test2 = 2 * 2 =\resultTwo\\

\FPeval{\resultThree}{round( \RoneValue * \RoneValue :2)}
test3 = \RoneValue * \RoneValue = \resultThree\\
test3a = \RoneValue * \RoneValue = \num{\resultThree}\\
%until now everything OK

test3a = \num[parse-numbers=false]{\RoneMax}\\% this offcourse works
%now NOK
test3a = \num{\RoneMax}
\FPeval{\resultFour}{round( \RoneMax * \RoneMax :2)}
test3 = \resultFour \\
test3a = \num{\resultFour}
\end{document}
```

The thing is that I can have several Families and Keys (each can be up to 15 or more) for which I then need to manually specify and extend the `\newcommand \RESFamilyName{#1}` to mimic the difference as `\newcommand \RESFamily**One**Name{#1}`.

I've been searching the net for something similar but so far havent found it or most likely missed it since my Latex knowledge is fairly fresh with these "core" things.

Thank you for your time and help.

**EDIT (NOT WORKING):**

```
\newcommand \csnshrt[2]{\csname #1#2\endcsname}%shorter \csname \endcsname
%
\newcommand \defkeyshrt{%START DEFINE@KEY-SHORT MACRO
    \foreach \n in {%
        Name,
        Address,
        City,
        Parameter,
        Whatever,
        XXX,
        YYY,
        ZZZ,
        etc,
        }{ \define@key{#1}{\n}{ \csnshrt{#1}{\n}{How To Add Value Here??} }}%\define@key{RESFamily}{Name}{ \newcommand \RESFamilyName{#1} }%
}%END DEFINE@KEY-SHORT MACRO

%USAGE
\defkeyshrt{RESFamily}%
\defkeyshrt{RESFamilyOne}%
\defkeyshrt{RESFamilyETC}%
```

With this the `define@key` would be automatically changed and I'd do it once in the `\defkeyshrt{RESFamily}` where before i'd need to manually change the `\define@key{RESFamily}{Name}{ \newcommand \RESFamilyName{#1} }` to reflect `\define@key{RESFamilyETC}{Name}{ \newcommand \RESFamilyETCName{#1} }` and so on for each and every parameter (Address, City, Whatever, YYY,...).

Comment: It would be really useful if you would give a compilable example and not some fragments. I can only guess what you want to achieve here, but I have some 'solution' in mind.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: It is essentially the same as in topic mentioned before. I've updated my question.

Comment: The original question was obscure, this one darkens it. It's by no means clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hopefully this will make things more clear. Currently when I create a new Family which has fairly similar keys (e.g. Name, Value) I need to manually refine the RESFamily `\newcommand \RESFamilyName{#1}` to be compliant with the new naming e.g. RESFamilyOne, RESFamilyTwo and etc. I'm doing this with editor's Find&Replace. When there are just a few keys these things are easy to fix but when I have 15 or more keys things can get messy. As i've checked, I have 35 families each with atleast 10 keys/values and based on my rough estimation the family count will probably double in the next few months.

Comment: I still don't understand this question.

Comment: I dont know what else to do to make things more clear. I do a Copy&Paste of a similar RESFamily and then manualy change the `\newcommand \RESFamilyName{#1}` naming to reflect e.g. `\newcommand \RESFamilyOneName{#1}`. What I'd like do is to make this once and not 20 or more times with the Find&Replace method that I now use in editor when I'm extending the define@key to reflect a new RESFamily. I've extended the initial question where the code clearly does not work. And I really hope this would make more sense to you, otherwise thank you very much for you time and effort.

Comment: @egreg and Christian: Any ideas or points towards what documentation I should search and look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { maag/variables }
 {
  unknown .code:n = \maag_defvar:Vn \l_keys_key_tl { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\newfamily}{mm}
 {
  \prop_clear:N \l_maag_family_prop
  \keys_set:nn { maag/variables } { #2 }
  \prop_new:c { g_maag_family_#1_prop }
  \prop_gset_eq:cN { g_maag_family_#1_prop } \l_maag_family_prop
 }

\prop_new:N \l_maag_family_prop

\cs_new_protected:Nn \maag_defvar:nn
 {
  \prop_put:Nnn \l_maag_family_prop { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \maag_defvar:nn { V }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevar}{mm}
 {
  \prop_item:cn { g_maag_family_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newfamily{FamilyOne}
 {
  Name = Gaius Iulius Caesar,
  Address = Palatinus,
  City = Roma,
  Parameter = Dictator,
  Whatever = Idae Martii,
 }

\newfamily{FamilyTwo}
 {
  Name = Iunius Brutus,
  Address = incognitum,
  City = Roma,
  Parameter = Conspirator,
  Whatever = ?,
 }

\begin{document}

\usevar{FamilyOne}{Name} was a famous guy.

\end{document}
```

As you see, after defining the infrastructure, you just need to give the new family name and the list of key-value pairs for the family members.

Instead of defining a macro for each key in each family, I believe it's better to have a generic command taking two arguments.

Comment: Huh, this code is way over my head at the moment and I have a lot of reading/learning to do now, starting with the `\ExplSyntaxOn`. But, made a fast example on my side and tried it out. I think it will eventualy fit into my Library design. Thank you.